# Trigger image picker on UITabBarController button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have made a `tabbar` in `storyboard` with 4 bar items, I connected all of them to other view controllers by rightclick dragging and setting `viewcontroller` segue. Now for the second button i want to show an `imagepicker` instead of a `viewcontroller`. When i delete the second segue from storyboard in `UITabBarController`, my 4th bar item disappears.

This is my tabview controller

```
class BaseTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    let arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState = ["home", "explore", "addIcon", "notification", "accountIcon"]
    let arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState = ["homeFilled", "exploreFilled", "addIcon", "notificaitonFilled", "accountIcon"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

        if let count = self.tabBar.items?.count {
            for i in 0..<count {
                let imageNameForSelectedState   = arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState[i]
                let imageNameForUnselectedState = arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState[i]

                self.tabBar.items?[i].selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageNameForSelectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                self.tabBar.items?[i].image = UIImage(named: imageNameForUnselectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            }
        }

    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if tabBar.items?.index(of: item) ?? 0 == 2 {
            //Clicked add tab, cancel segue and show imagepicker
        } else {
            selectedTabindex = tabBar.items?.index(of: item) ?? 0
        }
    }
}
```

How do I show image picker on 2nd bar button click

Comment: Should not use ImagePickerController Directly  Try to add Custom camera with AVCaptureSession https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/setting_up_a_capture_session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not Delete Second segue from storyboard put dummy view controller to show tab button inside tabbar. Implement UITabBarController controller's delegate method in subclass of UITabBarController and return false in shouldSelect method for second viewcontroller and present ImagePicker View for there.

Code:

```
class BaseTabBarController : UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return false
    }

}

extension BaseTabBarController : UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func  tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if self.viewControllers?.index(of:viewController) == 1 {
            // TO Do code for Image Picker and Present it 
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    }

}
```